# Probability puzzle on partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, extremal-combinatorics

Consider a set $U$ of size $n$ and let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all $(n/2)$-subsets of $U$ (assume $n$ is divisible by 4). Let $P$ be a partition of $\mathcal{S}$ into $k$ blocks $B_1,\dots,B_k$.

Now suppose we choose a set $C$ of $n/4$ elements uniformly at random from $U$.
Can we get a nontrivial lower bound on the probability that there exists a block $B_i$ and distinct subsets $S,S’ \in B_i$, for which $S \cap S’ \subseteq C$?

Clearly, this probability is $1$ for $k=1$ and $0$ for $k=|\mathcal{S}|$, but what happens in between? One approach that I tried was to analyze how much this probability reduces as $k$ doubles, but even that seems to be difficult.

**Update:** We can ssume that all blocks of $P$ are of the same size, to simplify things.

Comment: The answer depends on  the partition $P$. Do you intend that all the blocks are the same size?

Comment: @SamHopkins: Yes, we can assume that the blocks are of the same size. I will update the question.

Comment: @SamHopkins: $C$ should have exactly $n/4$ elements.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the blocks? You can choose the blocks so that the probability is 1 as long as $k \le |\mathcal{S}|-1$, by ensuring some $B_i$ contains some set $S$ as well as its complement.

Comment: @user7868: you're right that we can choose the blocks to maximize the probability, but I'm more interested in a lower bound on the probability that holds no matter how we choose the blocks.